# oracle sql totalize days for contiguos ranges

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with date ranges and i need to count the days only for the contiguos date ranges...

```
-----------------------------------
| table RANGES                    |
----------------------------------
| d_start    | d_end       | days |
| (date)     | (date)      | (num)|
-----------------------------------
| 2014-02-01 | 2014-02-05  |   4  |
| 2014-02-06 | 2014-02-11  |   5  |
| 2014-03-22 | 2014-03-25  |   3  |
| 2014-04-02 | 2014-04-10  |   8  |
| 2014-04-11 | 2014-04-20  |   9  |
-----------------------------------
```

I need to totalize days with break when the date ranges are not contiguos, a result like this:

```
| 2014-02-01 | 2014-02-11  |   9  |
| 2014-03-22 | 2014-03-25  |   3  |
| 2014-04-02 | 2014-04-20  |  17  |
```

i Tryed with LEAD to check if next record's d_start is equal d_end but i can't achieve the goal.

many thanks for any idea!
Marco

Comment: sorry it was a mistake :-(

Comment: I was talking about contiguos date, so when i say "next  record d_start is equal d_end" i mean two contiguos periods... as Sander the Softwarer has understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite tricky:

```
SQL> create table tmp$dates (d_start date, d_end date);

Table created

SQL> insert into tmp$dates values (DATE '2014-02-01', DATE '2014-02-05');

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into tmp$dates values (DATE '2014-02-06', DATE '2014-02-11');

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into tmp$dates values (DATE '2014-03-22', DATE '2014-03-25');

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into tmp$dates values (DATE '2014-04-02', DATE '2014-04-10');

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into tmp$dates values (DATE '2014-04-11', DATE '2014-04-20');

1 row inserted

SQL> select min(d_start), max(d_end), max(d_end) - min(d_start) + 1 n#
  2  from tmp$dates d
  3  start with d_start not in (select d_end + 1 from tmp$dates)
  4  connect by prior d_end = d_start - 1
  5  group by level - rownum
  6  order by 1;

MIN(D_START) MAX(D_END)          N#
------------ ----------- ----------
01.02.2014   11.02.2014          11
22.03.2014   25.03.2014           4
02.04.2014   20.04.2014          19
```